# package GDAL JAVA Binding and native library in a SWT plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, java-native-interface, swt, native

I want to package [GDAL](http://gdal.org/) and its JAVA binding into a SWT plug-in.
(P.S. GDAL use swig to generate Java binding)

I have all necessary native libraries and want to pack them into my Eclipse plug-in to let other people use it without installing GDAL on their computer.

The problem is that the JAVA Binding (or native lib itself) will lookup necessary native libraries from **PATH** (Window) or **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** (Linux) instead looking up those libs in a relative location. Furthermore, GDAL will look up some necessary geo definition data from the environment variable **GDAL_DATA** as well.

How can I solve those two problems to make a portable SWT plug-in?
1) package platform specific native libs
2) some environment variable look-up

It seems that eclipse cannot resolve dependent libs without having PATH set.
Bundle-NativeCode (see below) did not work.

If I try to directly call System.Library("SomethingNotExist") in my plugin;
then I get

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no SomethingNotExist in java.library.path
```

If I call System.Library("SomethingDoesExist") in my plugin, then I get

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: SomethingDoesExist.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

The file structure in my plug-in

```
org.gdal/
   + src/
   + nativelib/
      + linux32/
        + ...
      + linux32/
        + ...
      + win32/
        + ...
      + win64/
        + ...
   + META-INF
      + MANIFEST.MF
   + gdal-data/
   + gdal.jar
   + build.properties
```

The build.properties for this Plug-in

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               gdal.jar,\
               gdal-data/,\
               nativelib/
```

The Manifest for this Plug-in

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: GDAL
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.gdal
Bundle-Version: 1.8.1
Bundle-NativeCode: 
 nativelib/linux32/libgdal.so;
 nativelib/linux32/libgdalconstjni.so;
 nativelib/linux32/libgdaljni.so;
 nativelib/linux32/libogrjni.so;
 nativelib/linux32/libosrjni.so;
 osname=Linux; processor=x86,
 nativelib/linux64/libgdal.so;
 nativelib/linux64/libgdalconstjni.so;
 nativelib/linux64/libgdaljni.so;
 nativelib/linux64/libogrjni.so;
 nativelib/linux64/libosrjni.so;
 osname=Linux; processor=x86_64,
 nativelib/win32/gdal18.dll;
 nativelib/win32/gdalconstjni.dll;
 nativelib/win32/gdaljni.dll;
 nativelib/win32/geos_c.dll;
 nativelib/win32/iconv.dll;
 nativelib/win32/libcurl.dll;
 nativelib/win32/libeay32.dll;
 nativelib/win32/libexpat.dll;
 nativelib/win32/libmysql.dll;
 nativelib/win32/libpq.dll;
 nativelib/win32/libxml2.dll;
 nativelib/win32/ogrjni.dll;
 nativelib/win32/openjpeg.dll;
 nativelib/win32/osrjni.dll;
 nativelib/win32/pdflib.dll;
 nativelib/win32/proj.dll;
 nativelib/win32/spatialite.dll;
 nativelib/win32/sqlite3.dll;
 nativelib/win32/ssleay32.dll;
 nativelib/win32/xerces-c_2_8.dll;
 nativelib/win32/zlib1.dll;
 osname=win32; processor=x86,
 nativelib/win64/ogrjni.dll;
 nativelib/win64/gdal18.dll;
 nativelib/win64/xerces-c_2_8.dll;
 nativelib/win64/libexpat.dll;
 nativelib/win64/libpq.dll;
 nativelib/win64/spatialite.dll;
 nativelib/win64/libmysql.dll;    
 nativelib/win64/geos_c.dll;
 nativelib/win64/libcurl.dll;
 nativelib/win64/openjpeg.dll; 
 nativelib/win64/iconv.dll; 
 nativelib/win64/libeay32.dll;
 nativelib/win64/gdaljni.dll;
 nativelib/win64/osrjni.dll; 
 nativelib/win64/gdalconstjni.dll; 
 nativelib/win64/libxml2.dll; 
 nativelib/win64/pdflib.dll;
 nativelib/win64/proj.dll;
 nativelib/win64/sqlite3.dll;
 nativelib/win64/ssleay32.dll;
 nativelib/win64/zlib1.dll; 
 osname=win32; processor=x86_64
Bundle-ClassPath: gdal.jar,
 .,
 gdal-data/
Export-Package: org.gdal,
 org.gdal.gdal,
 org.gdal.gdalconst,
 org.gdal.ogr,
 org.gdal.osr
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
```

---

Comment: What exactly is the problem (what errors are reported by who)? OSGi will load your DLLs from your plugin according to `Bundle-NativeCode` section, so *JAVA Binding (or native lib itself) will lookup necessary native libraries from PATH* is not the case.

Comment: @Martti: really? I think the native code tries to load relevant libs from PATH and looks up some config data from other defined environment variable path.

Error Message: [[Native library load failed.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ogrjni.dll: Can't find dependent libraries]]

Comment: Yes, **native libs** are loading from PATH. The point I was trying to make is that this has nothing to do with Eclipse nor Java, but normal lib resolving of any program.

Comment: Yes, if I set PATH properly, it works (run as just a normal Java program)! But I can't set such PATH in a plug-in bundle and I dont' want users care about it. I just package all necessary libs in a plug-in, but it seems that eclipse (or OS) cannot resolve those libs without having PATH set.

Comment: Does it work if you load all necessary libs from Java code and won't rely on the "assembly resolver" of native code?

Comment: Do you mean System.loadLibrary()? doesn't it also depend on PATH?

Comment: `System.loadLibrary()` is where the `Bundle-NativeCode` section is used.

Comment: @Martti: I have tried it again. It seems that Bundle-NativeCode did not work for me. System.loadLibrary() cannot find the lib that I defined in MANIFEST.

Comment: You need to load the libs in order of dependency - first the ones that are independent and dependents after those.

Comment: you mean `Bundle-NativeCode: LibC; libB; LibA` if I have a dependency `LibA -dep-> LibB -dep-> LibC`? Actually in the Java Binding only JNI.dll is load from java. The other dependent libs seems to be loaded automatically via system.

Comment: No, I mean in the code: `System.loadLibrary("LibC"); System.loadLibrary("LibB"); System.loadLibrary("LibA");`

Comment: thanks I finally got your idea!

Answer (score 1):

For the environment issue of GDAL in Java

use `gdal.SetConfigOption`

http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-GDAL-DATA-td3744017.html

To set GDAL_DATA with the folder which can be read from a plugin bundle.

http://www.vogella.de/blog/2010/07/06/reading-resources-from-plugin/